# How to get logs when build fails in docker-py?

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

If I build an image using the high-level docker-py sdk, I get a BuildError on failure., eg

```
try:
    client.images.build(...)
except:
    print("Hey something wrong with image build!")
```

I know I can use the low level client API to directly hook in and stream logs, see [How can I detect when docker-py client.build() fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570014/how-can-i-detect-when-docker-py-client-build-fails).

Is there a way to get some useful debug output from the image build script without going down to the lower level api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Docker 3.x, the BuildError contains a new `build_log` variable which is a generator of output:

```
try:
    return client.images.build(...)
except BuildError as e:
    print("Hey something went wrong with image build!")
    for line in e.build_log:
        if 'stream' in line:
            logger.error(line['stream'].strip())
    raise
```